# Auto-Fill for Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, autofill, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet with conditional formatting that changes the background color of cell `H2` based on the contents of cell `F2`. I want to auto-fill this conditional formatting rule down the column, so that cell `H3` depends on `F3`, `H4` on `F4`, and so on.

When I drag the cell's formatting down the column (Auto-Fill), the conditional formatting rule doesn't get sequenced - the origin cell's rules just get copied verbatim.

Is there a workaround, besides manually editing the rule for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have some more details of how you established the rule that you have but *Custom formula is* of:

```
=H2=F2
```

and Range H2 should copy down as you require.

Comment: I'm using: Custom formula is =$H$2<>$F$2, which works great for row 2, but doesn't copy down.